# explanation of roulette wheel selection example

Tags: lisp, genetic-algorithm

I have a lisp program on roulette wheel selection,I am trying to understand the theory behind it but I cannot understand anything.
How to calculate the fitness of the selected strng?
For example,if I have a string 01101,how did they get the fitness value as 169?

Is it that the binary coding of 01101 evaluates to 13,so i square the value and get the answer as 169?

That sounds lame but somehow I am getting the right answers by doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fitness function" for a given problem is chosen (often) arbitrarily keeping in mind that as the "fitness" metric rises, the solution should approach optimality. For example for a problem in which the objective is to minimize a positive value, the natural choice for `F(x)` would be `1/x`.

For the problem at hand, it seems that the fitness function has been given as `F(x) = val(x)*val(x)` though one cannot be certain from just a single value pair of (x,F(x)).

Roulette-wheel selection is just a commonly employed method of fitness-based pseudo-random selection. This is easy to understand if you've ever played roulette or watched 'Wheel of Fortune'.

Let us consider the simplest case, where `F(x) = val(x)`,

Suppose we have four values, `1,2,3 and 4`.

This implies that these "individuals" have fitnesses `1,2,3 and 4` respectively. Now the probability of selection of an individual 'x1' is calculated as `F(x1)/(sum of all F(x))`. That is to say here, since the sum of the fitnesses would be `10`, the probabilities of selection would be, respectively, `0.1,0.2,0.3 and 0.4`.

Now if we consider these probabilities from a cumulative perspective the values of x would be mapped to the following ranges of "probability:

```
1 ---> (0.0, 0.1]
2 ---> (0.1, (0.1 + 0.2)] ---> (0.1, 0.3]
3 ---> (0.3, (0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3)] ---> (0.3, 0.6]
4 ---> (0.6, (0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3 + 0.4)] ---> (0.6, 1.0]
```

That is, an instance of a uniformly distributed random variable generated, say `R` lying in the normalised interval, `(0, 1]`, is four times as likely to be in the interval corresponding to `4` as to that corresponding to `1`.

To put it another way, suppose you were to spin a roulette-wheel-type structure with each `x` assigned a sector with the areas of the sectors being in proportion to their respective values of `F(x)`, then the probability that the indicator will stop in any given sector is directly propotional to the value of `F(x)` for that `x`.

Answer (score 1):

The fitness function you have is therefore `F=X^2`.

The roulette wheel calculates the proportion (according to its fitness) of the whole that that individual (string) takes, this is then used to randomly select a set of strings for the next generation.

Suggest you read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) a few times.